# C - How to write new line without tampering with the existing line in output text?

Tags: c, text, newline

I have this code

```
<....
 Gets input from input.txt, which contains several lines
 the code checks each lines, determining the usefulness by calculating BR and BL, 
 the 2 INT variables to detect whether the text is useful or not
 ....>

 if (BR > BL)

 //if the BR in a line is greater than the BL, I want to copy that line (from input.txt)
 //and paste it to output.txt. 
 //So then the output.txt will only contains lines that has BR > BL 

 {
    wr_file=fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fprintf (wr_file, "%s \n", text);
 }
```

The program can detect the BR and BL of each line correctly. But with that last code, I cant seem to properly copy the useful line from input.txt to output.txt

Lets say this is my input.txt :

```
1. carrot cabbage tomato
2. potato rice
3. cabbage eggplant
```

Supposedly, the 1st and 3rd lines are the useful ones. So the output.txt should be like this:

```
1. carrot cabbage tomato
3. cabbage eggplant
```

But instead it looked like this:

```
3. cabbage eggplantomato
```

As you can see, it did copy the 1st line, but when it has to write the 3rd line, it doesnt write it in a new line, but instead tamper with the 1st line.

Please help, how can I copy the lines correctly.

Comment: You should show more code, specifically how you are reading and writing the text.  A short complete example is best.

Comment: Looks like you don't NUL-terminate the lines you read; thus the previous contents of the tomato line is still in text[].

Comment: I suggest you add some output to `stdout` so you can see what values you're actually trying to write to the file and confirm their sanity.  Be careful too of using `fopen(... "w")` repeatedly... each time it truncates the file, overwriting the old content.  Multithreading is another possible issue here.

Comment: could you please show your code here what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's not possible to debug properly, but I assume, you problem is , you are calling

```
wr_file=fopen("output.txt", "w");
```

number of times, that's why your output is overwrittern and only the last write is retained. `fopen()` the target file only once, and keep the `fwrite()` in loop.

Also, you need to <strike>`NULL`</strike> `NUL` terminate your input [`text`] from the input file when using as a *string* [ex: passing to `fwrite()`].

Comment: nit-pick "you need to `NULL` terminate your input [`text`]" - I'd argue that `NULL` - in uppercase and marked up as code - refers to the constant for NULL pointers, where-as the ASCII code for character 0 is `NUL`... see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).

Comment: I am so sorry to have put such a minimal writing of my whole code, but nevertheless, youve managed to figure out the solution. Thank you very much, this is exactly the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is in the code that reads the file. When you read a line into a string, you should add a `\0`-character to terminate the string.

Answer (score 0):

The output file is being opened in "w" mode ie the write mode, so what happens is that when you write a line it overwrites the file content.
I would recommend you to use the

```
wr_file=fopen("output.txt", "w");
```

for writing the first line and

```
wr_file=fopen("output.txt", "a");
```

for writing the remaining lines.

**Update 1:**
Else try this add all the data that you want to write to a string(char []) and then write that string to the respective file. Reduces the number of times the files is accessed.